# Input form inserting data as numerical values rather than actual data

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I've got an input form I've added dummy data into this form and for some reason it is adding the data as numerical values, i.e. "1". I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, does it have anything to do with me selecting the `COUNT` of the e-mail before I upload this data?

Thanks in advance

My code is below:

register.php

```
    <div id="maincontentWrapper">

    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="contentWrapper"></div><!--End registerWrapper -->
            <article>
                <p>Welcome to iManage, please login in below.</p>
            </article>
        <div id="loginform">
            <div id="registerWrapper">
            <form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="insert.php">
            <h1><span class="log-in">Register</span></h1>
                    <p class="required"><span class="log-in">*Required Fields</span></p>
                    <div id="errorDiv"><?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['error']) & isset($_SESSION['formAttempt'])) {
                                unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
                                print "Errors encountered<br/>\n";
                                foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
                                print $error . "<br />\n";
                            } //end foreach
                            } //end if 
                    ?></div>

             <p class="float">
            <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Name*</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="showpassword"> 
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="nameError">Name is required</span>
        </p>
        <p class="float">
            <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Username*</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="usernameError">Username is required</span>
        </p>
        <p class="float">
            <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Password*</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> 
                    <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="passwordError">Password is required</span>
        </p>
           <p class="float">
            <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Verify Password*</label>
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Verify Password" class="showpassword"> 
                    <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="password2Error">Passwords dont match</span>
        </p>

         <p class="float">
            <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Email*</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="showpassword"> 
                    <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">Email is required or you have not entered a valid email address</span>
        </p>
        <p class="clearfix"> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></form>
        </p>   
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

class.Users.php

```
<?php
include("connect/class.Connect.php");
class Users extends Database {


 function preventaccess () {
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        die(header("Location: register.php"));
    }
}

function validate() {
    $_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

    if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }

     $_SESSION['error'] = array();

    $required = array("username","name","email","password","password2");

        //Check required fields
        foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$requiredField]) || $_POST[$requiredField] == "") {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = $requiredField . " is required.";
        }
        }


        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid e-mail address";
        }

        if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Passwords don't match";
        }
        //final disposition
        if (count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
        die(header("Location: register.php"));
        } else {
        unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
        }
}


public function insert() {

                    $result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=?");
                    $result->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
                    $result->execute();
                    $result->bind_result($email_count);
                    $result->fetch();//fecth
                    $result->close();   

                    if ($email_count > 0) {
                        echo "email exisits! click here to try <a href='register'>again</a>";
                        } else {
                            //escape the POST data for added protection
                            $username = isset($_POST['username']);
                            $cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);
                            $password = $cryptedPassword;
                            $name = isset($_POST['name']);
                            $email = isset($_POST['email']);
                            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            //var_dump($this->mysqli->error);
                            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $name, $email); // bind strings to the paramater

                                /* execute prepared statement */
                                $stmt->execute();
                                printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
                                /* close statement and connection */
                                $stmt->close();
                } // end email_count and insert to table
            } // end function



} // End users class
$run = new Users();
        $run->preventaccess();
        $run->validate();
        $run->insert();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your made a little mistake. You've written:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
```

but what I think you really wanted to do is:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
```

In fact, you are not storing username, etc. itself but if these values are sent. The boolean value `true` is then converted to the number `1`.

To make it work you also have to change it for `$name` and `$email` since you've also used `isset` there.

Comment: that worked, is that something I would have to do with the password field too? as currently I've left it as so,         `$cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);` or should I use the same format as above? Will accept your answer in 5 minutes have to wait for the ticker!

Comment: @gutigrewal You also have to do it with name and email. You haven't used `isset` for password so you don't have to do it there.

Comment: yeah sorry I did do that with the other fields just wasn't sure if I should do it with the password field, but thanks for your help @Jimmy T.